# How can I get 4 vertices's coordinate of the virtual plane?

Tags: swift, arkit

I made the virtual plane (SCNPlane) based on real table through Scenekit. Additionally, I want to know 4 vertices's coordinate of the virtual plane.

[Click here to see image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On0pW.png)

Comment: Is your virtual plane an SCNPlane?

Comment: Yes. SCNPlane of SceneKit

Answer (score 7):

You can get the coordinates of the bounding box, just as [BlackMirrorz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816868/josh-robbins) said.

```
let (min, max) = planeNode.boundingBox
```

This will give you opposite corners (min and max) as SCNVector3 objects. Those coordinates will be *relative to the object*, unrotated, untranslated, and unscaled. Derive the other two corner coordinates in the 2d plane. Don't worry about the Z axis. An SCNPlane is fundamentally a 2D object.

```
let bottomLeft = SCNVector3(min.x, min.y, 0)
let topRight = SCNVector3(max.x, max.y, 0)

let topLeft = SCNVector3(min.x, max.y, 0)
let bottomRight = SCNVector3(max.x, min.y, 0)
```

Then call

```
let worldBottomLeft = planeNode.convertPosition(bottomLeft, to: rootNode)
let worldTopRight = planeNode.convertPosition(topRight, to: rootNode)

let worldTopLeft = planeNode.convertPosition(topLeft, to: rootNode)
let worldBottomRight = planeNode.convertPosition(bottomRight, to: rootNode)
```

to convert each coordinate to world space. The system will do the rotation, translation, and scaling for you.

Answer (score 1):

An SCNNode has a `boundingBox` property which refers to the:

> The minimum and maximum corner points of the object’s bounding box.

```
var boundingBox: (min: SCNVector3, max: SCNVector3) { get set }
```

Whereby:

> Scene Kit defines a bounding box in the local coordinate space using
>   two points identifying its corners, which implicitly determine six
>   axis-aligned planes marking its limits. For example, if a geometry’s
>   bounding box has the minimum corner {-1, 0, 2} and the maximum corner
>   {3, 4, 5}, all points in the geometry’s vertex data have an
>   x-coordinate value between -1.0 and 3.0, inclusive. The coordinates
>   provided when reading this property are valid only if the object has a
>   volume to be measured. For a geometry containing no vertex data or a
>   node containing no geometry, the values min and max are both zero.

As such it is quite easy to get the coordinates of an `SCNNode`:

```
/// Returns The Size Of An SCNode
///
/// - Parameter node: SCNNode
func getSizeOfModel(_ node: SCNNode){

   //1. Get The Bouding Box Of The Node
   let (min, max) = node.boundingBox

   //2. Get It's Z Coordinate
   let zPosition = node.position.z

   //3. Get The Width & Height Of The Node
   let widthOfNode = max.x - min.x
   let heightOfNode = max.y - min.y

   //4. Get The Corners Of The Node
   let topLeftCorner = SCNVector3(min.x, max.y, zPosition)
   let bottomLeftCorner = SCNVector3(min.x, min.y, zPosition)
   let topRightCorner = SCNVector3(max.x, max.y, zPosition)
   let bottomRightCorner = SCNVector3(max.x, min.y, zPosition)

   print("""
        Width Of Node = \(widthOfNode)
        Height Of Node = \(heightOfNode)
        Bottom Left Coordinates = \(bottomLeftCorner)
        Top Left Coordinates = \(topLeftCorner)
        Bottom Right Coordinates = \(bottomRightCorner)
        Top Right Coordinates = \(topRightCorner)
    """)

 }
```