# Calculating the 4 vertices' positions of a rotated SCNPlane in an ARKit experience

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I am working on an iOS App and am currently trying to get the coordinates (in reference to the world/rootNode) of the 4 vertices of a rotated SCNNode in an AR Experience

From what I've seen from debugging this mess, the Bounding box of a rotated and tilted SCNPlane is still level with the world origin.

I've tried the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790968/how-can-i-get-4-verticess-coordinate-of-the-virtual-plane) thread.

The plane that I'm trying to detect is put directly on top of a image, that was detected by ARKit:

```swift
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

    updateQueue.async {

        // Create a plane to visualize the initial position of the detected image.
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                             height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.opacity = 0.25

        /*
         `SCNPlane` is vertically oriented in its local coordinate space, but
         `ARImageAnchor` assumes the image is horizontal in its local space, so
         rotate the plane to match.
         */
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        /*
         Image anchors are not tracked after initial detection, so create an
         animation that limits the duration for which the plane visualization appears.
         */
        planeNode.runAction(self.imageHighlightAction)

        // This is where I tried to calculate the edge
        let (min, max) = planeNode.boundingBox

        let topLeft = SCNVector3(min.x, max.y, 0)

        let worldTopLeft = planeNode.convertPosition(topLeft, to: self.sceneView.scene.rootNode)

        let world2dTopLeft = self.sceneView.projectPoint(worldTopLeft)


        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
}
```

The expected result was some kind of 2D position on the screen, that would be directly on top of the corner in the 3D view, but what I always get are huge numbers, like `x: 8847.291, y: -10651.121`

Has anyone got a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

I need to calculate this doing some advanced math that some of you can probably explain way better than me.

The working copy (for Swift 4.2) is:

```
let imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor! // provided by renderer()
let scale: CGFloat!             // UIDevice.main.scale (device scale)

// returns a transform matrix from a point
let imageTransform: (_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> float4x4 = {x, y in
    var tf = float4x4(diagonal: float4(repeating: 1))
    tf.columns.3 = float4(x: Float(x), y: 0, z: Float(y), w: 1)
    return tf
}

let imageSize = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize
let worldTransform = imageAnchor.transform

let topLeft = imageTransform(-imageSize.width / 2, -imageSize.height / 2)
let topRight = imageTransform(imageSize.width / 2, -imageSize.height / 2)
let bottomLeft = imageTransform(-imageSize.width / 2, imageSize.height / 2)
let bottomRight = imageTransform(imageSize.width / 2, imageSize.height / 2)

let transformTopLeft = worldTransform * topLeft
let transformTopRight = worldTransform * topRight
let transformBottomLeft = worldTransform * bottomLeft
let transformBottomRight = worldTransform * bottomRight

let pointTopLeft = self.sceneView.projectPoint(SCNVector3(x: transformTopLeft.columns.3.x,
                                                          y: transformTopLeft.columns.3.y,
                                                          z: transformTopLeft.columns.3.z))

let pointTopRight = self.sceneView.projectPoint(SCNVector3(x: transformTopRight.columns.3.x,
                                                           y: transformTopRight.columns.3.y,
                                                           z: transformTopRight.columns.3.z))

let pointBottomLeft = self.sceneView.projectPoint(SCNVector3(x: transformBottomLeft.columns.3.x,
                                                             y: transformBottomLeft.columns.3.y,
                                                             z: transformBottomLeft.columns.3.z))

let pointBottomRight = self.sceneView.projectPoint(SCNVector3(x: transformBottomRight.columns.3.x,
                                                              y: transformBottomLeft.columns.3.y,
                                                              z: transformBottomLeft.columns.3.z))

// Those are the CGPoints, projected to the screen
let cgTL = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pointTopLeft.x)*scale, y: extent.height-CGFloat(pointTopLeft.y)*scale)
let cgTR = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pointTopRight.x)*scale, y: extent.height-CGFloat(pointTopRight.y)*scale)
let cgBL = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pointBottomLeft.x)*scale, y: extent.height-CGFloat(pointBottomLeft.y)*scale)
let cgBR = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pointBottomRight.x)*scale, y: extent.height-CGFloat(pointBottomRight.y)*scale)
```

This has worked just fine. I hope somebody can explain what I did there.

Comment: Trying to use your solution to map an ARPlaneAnchor's vertices to world coordinates, but the results are still off (I want to wrap a plane in 4 nodes). Any ideas how to do this? Seems very related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the z position to zero when transforming from local space to world space. You can use the bounding box `min` and `max` values without modifying them:

```
let (min, max) = planeNode.boundingBox

// local space to world space
let minWorld = planeNode.convertPosition(min, to: self.sceneView.scene.rootNode)
let maxWorld = planeNode.convertPosition(max, to: self.sceneView.scene.rootNode)

// world space to screen space
let minScreen = self.sceneView.projectPoint(minWorld)
let maxScreen = self.sceneView.projectPoint(maxWorld)
```

You can then use `minScreen` and `maxScreen`'s x and y coordinates and ignore z.